# Jinja escaping beginning of comment tag

Tags: ansible, jinja2, template-engine, templating

I am trying to create a bash script in a jinja template. I have the following line:

```
SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}
```

But it throws an error:

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: Missing end of comment tag
```

After investigating I found out that a `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` block can be used to take literals, but it still doesn't work for `{#` obtaining a similar error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while templating
Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: Missing end of comment tag
```

Is there a workaround for this without changing bash logic?

Thanks

UPDATE: including examples

ansible playbook:

```
... more ansible playbook stuff ...    

tasks:
- name: create script 
  template:
    src: "src/path/to/script.sh.j2"
    dest: "dest/path/to/output/script.sh"

- name: user data script as string
  set_fact:
    userdata: "{{ lookup('file', 'path/to/script.sh') }}"

- name: some cloudformation thing
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: "stack_name"
    state: present
    region: "some region"
    template: "path/to/template/cloudformation.json"
    template_parameters:
      ... a bunch of params ...
      UserDataScript: "{{ userdata }}"
    tags:
      ... tags ..
      metadata: "... metadata ..."
  register: cloudformation_results
```

jinja template (script.sh.j2):

```
... more script stuff ...

SOME_ARRAY="some array with elements"
SOME_ARRAY=($SOME_ARRAY)
SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}

... more script stuff ...
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

This line: `SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}` caused in the first template task to ask for a closing `#}` comment tag. First fix adding raw block:

```
{% raw %}
SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}
{% endraw %}
```

Fixes the templating part, but the cloudformation module also applies templating substitutions so it would then have the same error.

**THE FIX:**

```
{% raw %}
SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${{ '{#' }}SOME_ARRAY[@]}
{% endraw %}
```

First template module removes raw block and keeps `{{ '{$' }}` and cloudformation module finds `{{ '{$' }}` and applies literal substitution.

Comment: Using `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` seems to solve the problem for me when I try it out. Can you include an example template and Ansible playbook in the question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I was asking specifically for an example that, when run by itself, demonstrates the problem you've described. I've added answer that takes your examples here and plugs them into a playbook, and everything seems to work. If you run the same playbook and template and it doesn't work, let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I put this into `script.sh`:

```
SOME_ARRAY="some array with elements"
SOME_ARRAY=($SOME_ARRAY)
{% raw %}
SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}
{% endraw %}
```

And this into `playbook.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: create script
      template:
        src: ./script.sh.j2
        dest: ./script.sh
```

When I run `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`, I get as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [create script] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]
```

And `script.sh` looks like:

```
SOME_ARRAY="some array with elements"
SOME_ARRAY=($SOME_ARRAY)

SOME_ARRAY_COUNT=${#SOME_ARRAY[@]}
```

As far as I can tell, everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: It worked, what i didnt add to the example, is that following the template task i have a cloudformation task, and this module is templating again so it finds the `{#` and the error pops. Thanks for the help!